# JQuery file download adds base url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery.fileDownload.js library with a URL to a REST-like service that runs on the same server as the client-application. The problem is that the client applications hostname is something like this: http:// www.site.com/application/ but the Rest service runs on http:// www.site.com/api/v1/data/ When I send the url to the REST service the fileDownload library adds the base URL of the application but I want the hostname without the path to /application. 
Here is some of the code:

```
var zipUrl = "/api/v1/data/1/zip?file=<file1>&file=<file2>"
zipFiles(zipUrl);

function zipFiles(url) {
   $.fileDownload(url, {
     successCallback: function (url) {

     $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
     $('.olPopup').hide();
 },
 failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {

     $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
     $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true, resizable: false });
     $('.olPopup').hide();
 }
});
};
```

In firebug I can see that the GET method is used to this URL: http:// www.site.com/application/api/v1/data/ and not http:// www.site.com/api/v1/data/

I'm using jquery 1.9.1 and version v.1.3.0 of jquery.fileDownload.js

Is there some way to fix this?